# Simple Java Sentence Classification program

Tags: java, nlp, sentence

I need some help with a form of sentence classification program.

A program that reads a files and checks each sentence in the file to locate any ‘keywords’. Keywords are in another file with words written inside it. If it finds a keyword, it writes that sentence into another file.

So far I am cool with the reading of the input file and splitting into sentences and writing of the output file

Can you please give some direction with how the program will read each sentence in the first file and compare it  against the words in the second file and if it locates a keyword in the sentence write into a third file?

Many thanks!

Comment: Load all the words into a `HashSet`; split input by words; use `set.contains(word)`

Comment: Wouldn't a regexp approach be more suitable??

Comment: @user992484 What's a "regexp approach"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner to read the file and have directly words extracted.

You can load all the keyword to compare in a TreeSet, then if found you write to the FileWriter

Answer (score 0):

Keywords are a set, I presume. You'll need to have fast access to them, so use `HashSet`.

If your keywords should match only and only on exact counterparts in your sentenece, split your sentence by any whitespaces (`\\s+` regex) and try to match each word of a sentence with the elements in keywords.

You can build a dependency grap this way, so you can have a HashMap where kewords are keys, and values are Sets of sentences referencing that keyword.

In the end, you could end up with something like this:

```
[Keyword="StackOverflow"]
    [Values=
        "I like posting on StackOverflow.",
        "StackOverflow is cool."
    ]
[Keyword="posting"]
    [Values=
        "I like posting on StackOverflow."
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give a PHP based solution-

1. Parse the sentence string.
2. Use strtok() function, and define common punctuation(",'()/ etc) as tokenizers/classifiers.
3. form an array/set of the data dictionary containing the pre-defined words.
4. Use preg_match() function, for complete word match, u might wanna use specified structures to build the array as--> $variable = array ("/(\bword1\b)/", "/(\bword2\b)/").
5. For reference purposes/specifications of the above mentioned functions, search the php docs at - http://www.php.net/

Hope i could help.

Cheers.